# Image DIV Covering Child DIV

Tags: php, css, html

I have a simple program that echoes images out to a page from a database. I want to have a child element, just a simple slightly transparent box shown on top of the images.

I know child elements always has a higher z-index than it's parent but the image always covers over the box I want on top. When the page is loading I can see the box in the position I want but then when the images load and the box it disappears.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EBvCZ/

## PHP

```
echo '<div id="wrapper">';
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {                                      
      echo '<div id="picback"><div id="centerpic"><a href="image.php?photo_id='.$data['photo_id'].'" title="View Photo"><'.'img src="resizeimage.php?photo_id='.$data['photo_id'].'"></a>';
      echo '<br style="clear:both;" />';
      echo '<div id="titlepic">This is an image</div>';
        echo '</div></div>';
   }
echo '</div>
```

## CSS

```
#wrapper {
   overflow:auto;
   width:1000px;
   height:1000px;
   margin: 20px auto;
}

#titlepic {
   background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   top:100px;
   width:200px;
   height:35px;
   position:relative;
}

#centerpic {
    position:relative;
   margin:auto;
   width: 200px;
   height: 150px;
   top:18.75px;
   overflow:hidden;
}

#picback { 
   position:relative;
   margin:10px 23px;
   top:75px;
   float:left; 
   width:250px;
   height:187.5px;  
   overflow:hidden;
}

#picback:hover {
   background-color:rgb(190,190,190); 
   -webkit-border-radius:0.4em;  
   -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XKHZv/3/

I did some .css changes and also moved one div before the titlepic.

Here is your new .css:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow:auto;
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#titlepic {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width:200px;
    height:35px;
    position:relative;
    clear: both;
}
#centerpic {
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    top:18.75px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#picback {
    position:relative;
    margin:10px 23px;
    top:75px;
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height: 203.75px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#picback:hover {
    background-color:rgb(190, 190, 190);
    -webkit-border-radius:0.4em;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
```

Then you also have to move a div closing to before the title pic.

Comment: Thanks, actually I figured out all I need to do was close the div "centerpic" then echo the box div, which is what I see you did. I should have answered back sooner that I got it, sorry.  I am still not sure why putting the box in centerpic doesn't work as the child should have come on top but it works now! Super thanks for the jsfiddle and CSS!

Comment: Yeah, no problem! Spent maybe 15 minutes looking at it, but it's work it for a SO buddy.